# Raise an event from inside native c function?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am developing an application that does a callback to a native c function after playing a system sound.  I would like to raise an event when this happens, so a subscriber on my view may handle it.

```
-(void) completionCallback(SystemSoundID mySSID, void* myself) {
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SoundFinished" object: myself];
}
```

I recieve `unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`

On the view, I have the following code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(soundStopped) name:@"SoundFinished" object:nil];
```

...

```
-(void) soundStopped: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"Sound Stopped");
}
```

I am extremely new to objective-c, where am I going wrong?

Update The exact error is:

```
    2011-04-18 19:27:37.922 AppName[5646:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BackgroundTestViewController soundStopped]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13b4b0'
```

Comment: the reason for your second error is that the macro expands to [[[NSNotificationCenter] defaultCenter]]

Comment: Note what @Chris has said: your `center` macro represents an object, hence `[[center] post…]` is invalid syntax just like `[[obj] method…]` is invalid syntax. In `completionCallback()`, change `[[center] post…]` to `[center post…]`.

Comment: @Chris Thanks -- I removed this issue, as it isn't the real problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-soundStopped` and `-soundStopped:` are two different method names. The colon is part of the method name, but you left it out in your call to `-addObserver:selector:name:`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your notification handler (you have registered a selector that is not handled by the observer). Show us how you add the observer. There is no problem sending a notification from a "plain C" function.

Comment: Just as I thought, you have the selector name wrong in the addObserver - see Caleb's answer for the fix.